# Google Spreadsheets. How to count cells that fit a dynamic range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, countif

please help!

I have a row of numeric elements.

For each element in the row I want to count elements that meet the following equation from the row:

```
a*(1-d) <= x <= a*(1+d)
```

where:

- `a` is the current element,
- `x` is the comparing element,
- `d` is a constant.

COUNTIF doesn't work.

```
=COUNTIF($O$3:O;">=O3*(1-$B$22)"&"<=O3*(1+$B$22)")
=COUNTIF($O$3:O; AND($O$3:O>=O3*(1-$B$22);$O$3:O<=O3*(1+$B$22))
```

As a result, I would like to see a second row where counts are stored.

Thank you.

My worst attempts list:)

```
=COUNTIF($O$3:O;">=O3*(1-$B$22)"&"<=O3*(1+$B$22)")
=COUNTIF($O$3:O,>O3*(1-$B$22))-COUNTIF($O$3:$O$152,<O3*(1+$B$22))
=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(AND($O$3:$O$152>=O3*(1-$B$22);$O$3:$O$152<=O3*(1+$B$22))))
=DCOUNTA($O$3:$O$152, ””, >1000)
=COUNTIF($O$3:$O$152; {>=O3*(1-$B$22),<=O3*(1+$B$22)})
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF($O$3:O; AND($O$3:O>=O3*(1-$B$22);$O$3:O<=O3*(1+$B$22))))
=SUM(COUNT(IF(AND($O$3:O>=O3*(1-$B$22);$O$3:O<=O3*(1+$B$22));1)))
=COUNT(AND($O$3:O>=O3*(1-$B$22);$O$3:O<=O3*(1+$B$22)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A2:A10 is where your current elements are (a). B2:B10 (x) is the comparison number, and F1 is where the constant (d) is.

```
=arrayformula(sumproduct((A2:A10-$F$1<B2:B10)*(A2:A10+$F$1>B2:B10)))
```

Comment: Thank you for response. The thing is, that comparison numbers are from the row where current elements are.

Comment: That's what the above formula does. It worked for my sample - but it seems you've found another solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

```
=count( 
    iferror( 
        filter( $O$3:O ; $O$3:O >= O3 * ( 1-$B$22 ) ; $O$3:O <= O3* ( 1+$B$22 ) )
    )
 )
```

But what should I do to extend $O$3:O to $O$3:P ?

Comment: To extend search range I wrote:

=COUNTUNIQUE( iferror( filter( $O$3:O ; $O$3:O >= O4 * ( 1-$B$22 ) ; $O$3:O <= O4*  ( 1+$B$22 ) ) ) ;  iferror( filter( $P$3:P ; $P$3:P >= O4 * ( 1-$B$22 ) ; $P$3:P <= O4*  ( 1+$B$22 ) ) ))

But I think it is not the best way to do so:)
Also I replaced COUNT to COUNTUNIQUE because I needed only unique values.